# John had $500 Anna has $400 and Peter had $700. Who has the most? Is the answer Who? I don’t think so

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation

**I believe that a question mark at the end of a sentence or statement defines it as a question. If there is no question mark at the end of the statement,then it’s a statement.** Said riddle. John had $500 Anna has $400 and Peter had $700. Who has the most? T**he riddle ends with a question mark, so, for me it’s a question and not a statement. Your thoughts please.** Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is the trick that makes it fun. Anna has the most. All we know of the others is how much they *had* in the past.

Comment: https://youtu.be/kTcRRaXV-fg

Comment: Who says Anna has the most?  If this were an SAT multiple choice question, the answer would be: not enough information to answer.  Maybe John had $500, and then he took Peter's $700.

Comment: The question appears to be about punctuation, and not the actual riddle used as an example.

Comment: This looks like nonsense. If you're really Asking about how much John, Anna and Peter had or have, then please correct your wording. 

If your Question turns on "had or have" why not take it to a site dealing in riddles?

Else, what are you really Asking?

Answer (score 0):

A riddle in the traditional form either consists of, or ends, with a question. Your riddle ends with the question "Who has the most?".